# Make it easier to find queries a user wrote on the Data.Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

The saved queries page on the User Profile Page doesn't have paging and only lists the last 50 queries by modification date so once its more that 50 I can't see it ([I apparently have over  100 saved queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/users?page=14)).

Also the search box doesn't support searches like `user:me` or `user:2997` so I can't find the older ones unless I remember the title of the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part completed, we now have paging, will see about adding the user:me as a ninja search thing